# DWR dwrsessionid per browser instance instead of per user session

Tags: dwr

DWR is using DWRSessionID token for CSRF protection and it is not changing for each user session means logout from application is not changing the DWRSessionID and we will see same DWRSessionID by logging again without closing the browser.

This could be an issue (CSRF) if somebody steal the DWRSessionID and trying to send the links via email it will process the link if user is logged in again tinto the application as DWR is using the same DWRSessionID per browser instance instead of user session.

Is the above really an issue for CSRF or it is ok to have same DWRSessionID per browser instance instead of per user session.

Comment: If I'm understanding this question correctly, it might be a better fit for the [Security Stack](https://security.stackexchange.com/). It seems to be asking about general security best practice as opposed to a specific code issue.

Comment: This is specific to DWR implementation only and I am checking whether it is correct to have DWRSessionID per browser instance instead of per user session as this could leak the DWRSessionID and can spoof the users later.